# Handling Pointer To Array in Private Class.?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This is my first question at this website .. Referring to my friend,, he learns alot from here  ;), Now its' my turn i think .. :)

Dear respected members.. At this point i'm fully tensed and much frustrated to find out, what should i do with my code to work ..!!
Well i'm a student with basic knowledge of c++, in the current semester our hands on Object Oriented Programming .. 
This task is being done to clarify the concept of Classes (Private and Public), furthermore, Initialization, Sort Array, Searching for key etc.

I know, when we use dynamic memory, we have to write constructors, destructors etc, & i'm puzzled with that.. i think problem in parameters, or copy constructor, deep, shallow copy.
i don't know what it should be done !!! 
Well I'm not a professional sir.... So i'm sorry about that. !!

if someone guide me with my code with little examples regarding to arrays, pointers in classes, how can i handle. . . :( :(  that is much Appreciated Sir.

```
// Constructor.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class IntArray
{
private:

    int size;
    int *values;

public:

    void InputData() const;
    void OutputData() const;
    void Search() const;
    void Bubble() const;
    IntArray(int size)
    {
        values = new int[size];
    }
};

void IntArray::InputData()  const
{
        cout << "==> Entering Data <==" << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
        cout << ">> Enter Element #" << i+1 << ": ";
        cin >> values[i];
        }
}

void IntArray::OutputData() const
{
    cout << "==> Printing Data <==" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        cout << values[i] << " ,";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
void IntArray::Search() const
{
    int key;
    cout << "Please Enter A KEY To Find: ";
    cin >> key;
    int index = 0;
    bool found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if ((!found) && (key == values[i]))
        {
            index = i;
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (found)
    {
        cout << "KEY Found At The Index: " << index+1 << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "KEY is not present." << endl;
    }
    cout << '\n' << endl;
}

void IntArray::Bubble() const
{
    for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
        {

            if (values[j] > values[i])
            {
                int temp = values[j];
                values[j] = values[i];
                values[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int size = 5;
    IntArray u(size);
    u.InputData();
    u.OutputData();
    u.Search();
    u.Bubble();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your exact question? This isn't a site for general questions, but for targetted Q&A.

Comment: Yes bro. This code never gives me any output .. ?!
i don't know what to do with that ..

Comment: @user2337036 No output at all?

Comment: I've searched .. but didn't find any suitable information .. most of the examples are in static memory so default constructors and destructors are there to do the work but when using dynamic .. we have to write in our own to avoid garbage, memory leak etc. :/

Comment: yes, it is only printing .. 
the cout statement: Entering Data & Printing Data ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can understand from your comments in your question and answers, you are in a very bad situation: your instructor is BADLY USING THE WRONG TOOL TO DO THE JOB (It will be interesting if he read this site as well).

It is teaching you OOP using a non-OOP-pure language (like C++) teaching it you like it is  Java, thus generating confusion.

So you end-up managing dynamic memory in the wrong way (new[] in ctor, but no dtor and hence no delete[] and no copy and assign - hence sharing of dynamic data and potential double deletion), having mysterious doubt about functions with parameter (respect to *static memory (?!?) functions*), with an instructor who never told about a basic standard class (like std::vector) but pretends you to use dynamic allocated arrays...

What to say? It's HARD, VERY HARD.

My suggestion, is stop a while and try reading a more "industrial C++" based tutorial.
([This one](http://relisoft.com/book/preface.html) can really be useful! but follow it page by page!)

Comment: Yes Sir .. I agree :) . Thank you Sir for your precious suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You don't set the `size` member in your constructor, so it has an indeterminate value and accessing it in `InputData` gives you undefined behaviour.

```
IntArray(int size)
{
    this->size = size;
    values = new int[size];
}
```

Better yet, use the member initialization list (it's what it's for!):

```
IntArray(int size)
  : size(size), values(new int[size])
{ }
```

You should also implement a destructor to destroy dynamically allocated array of `int`s:

```
~IntArray()
{
  delete[] values;
}
```

Take a look at the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) to see that you should also be implementing the copy constructor and copy assignment operator.

Comment: That is not the only mistake. What about Rule of Three? The destructor is missing completely! Also, the important Q why not simply use `std::vector`?

Comment: Sir .. Till know my instructor never tells us about vectors.. !! also i understand the first one but the second one member initialization list . !! i didn't get it ..

Comment: WOW it works .. I can't believe .. Thank you so much ..

Comment: Sir, can i give parameters in the public function.. can i write like this. !! void InputData(int values[], int size) const; as we do in static memory functions .. ??????

Comment: The only problem left is: it will not sort the array .. !!

Comment: Code workx now .. i actually forget to call the print function again after sort the array.. !! The credit goes to you, the site and the members .. 
not to my teacher .. i learned here .. 
Thank You, So Much Guys .. 
Stay Blessed .. !!